# float left query not covered by parent

Tags: css

Following HTML block:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="background-color: #fecfff;">
        <div style="float:left;">
            <div style="height:40px; width:40px; background-color:Red"> </div>
            Karl Mac
        </div>

        <div>
            some comments details<br />
            <div style="padding-top: 10px">
                links
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Produces following:

[image]

How can I have Karl Mac too covered with color of parent container in this 2 column layout?
If I add "overflow:auto", it gets fixed in Firefox and Chrome. But issue persists in IE.
thanks!

Comment: you're missing a closing </div> tag

Comment: add to your wrapping div also the style float:left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've done for Chrome & Firefox:

```
overflow: auto;
```

To make it work in old IE as well:

```
overflow: auto; zoom: 1;
```

`zoom` enables "hasLayout" in old IE, which resolves many CSS bugs. There are also other ways to enable hasLayout, for more info: http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

Comment: Never heared of "Zoom" before. It works. +1 for the zoom thing :)

Comment: I should add, zoom is non-standard, it's a proprietary IE extension to CSS. I prefer it as a method to enable hasLayout as it has very few side effects. Only use in a conditionally commented out IE specific style sheet if you want your page to pass validation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `<div style="clear:both;"><div>` in the main div.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="background-color: #fecfff;">
        <div style="float:left;">
            <div style="height:40px; width:40px; background-color:Red"> </div>
            Karl Mac
        </div>

        <div>
            some comments details<br />
            <div style="padding-top: 10px">
                links
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"><div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/cCuab/

Comment: This works and resolves my issue. Unfortunately only one post can be marked as answer... But this is a resolution too.